# SwiftUI AppDelegate not working correctly

Tags: ios, swiftui, appdelegate

This is my main file code:

```
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("Your code here")
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct CouponDeckApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

The AppDelegate code doesn't seem to be running every time I open the app, as it should be. I have no idea what could be causing this problem. Does anybody know why this is happening, and how I should fix it?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm running my code on the simulator, maybe the problem is there?

Edit: My apologies, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want the code to run when your open the app, not downloaded and opened for the first time. Like when you click on the icon on the home screen and it opens the app.

Comment: The code that you've provided works as expected -- when the app launches, "Your code here" is printed to the console. Are you trying to do something when the app transfers from background to foreground but is not actually launched from scratch again?

Comment: @jnpdx yes basically whenever you tap on the app icon on the home screen and it opens, not when it has been downloaded from scratch.

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement code in [`willEnterForeground`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623076-applicationwillenterforeground)

Answer (score -3):

you could try this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  // <--- here

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("\n----------> in here \n")
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `UIResponder` change in this case?

Comment: Sure, but what behavior does that change related to this question? Especially since it *cannot* become a first responder, even. Merely saying that it *could* conform to some of those methods doesn't change whether `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` gets called, correct?

Comment: The downvote is not mine, by the way -- I'm just not clear on what this changes

Comment: someone does not like it, although it works very well for me, maybe it doesn't work for whoever.